# ERROR 404 | NOT FOUND host con Laravel 5.8

Tags: html5, laravel-5, php7, error404

He subido un proyecto Laravel 5.8 al Hostalia y dentro de otros errores ya corregidos ahora me sali este en el Log del host:

```js
 [15/Apr/2019:20:29:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 519 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"
```

Y también este en los Registros del host (los dos a la vez):

```html
    Internal error ;-P
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/smb/log-file/browser-data/id/201">GET&nbsp;/smb/log-file/browser-data/id/201</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

Necesito ayuda porque ya no se por donde ir.. Desde luego gracias!

Comment: Hola, revisa tus rutas ya que puede ser que no estes accesando correctamente a tu controlador y a tu vista.

Comment: Muy buenas! He revisado todas las rutas y controladores y no encontré el error.

Comment: Utilizo las plantillas **blade.php** pero no hago uso del **@section** ni del **@yield**, si no que utilizo **@include** para incluir header, section y footer. Crees que podria estar hai el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Blade para heredar de otra plantilla de utiliza @extends('layout'), quita el @import.

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('title', 'Page Title') @section('sidebar') @parent <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p> @endsection @section('content') <p>This is my body content.</p> @endsection
```